# How to validate a custom ASP.net control before postback

Tags: asp.net, validation, custom-controls, postback

I've created a custom control in a class project(DLL) and am using it in a page where I have the standard ASP.net required field validator control to ensure some property of the custom control is filled by the user.

For some reason, validation only happens after postback. I need the validation to happen on the client-side before postback i.e in a similar manner to the way a standard text box is validated by the ASP.net validator controls.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried some thing...

Comment: tried what? Yes I tried some ideas from the internet and none of them has helped me in this specific scenario

Comment: have You used any Code, if u could please give the code here

Answer (score 2):

you can use ClientValidationFunction property of CustomValidator.

```
  <asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1"
       ControlToValidate="Text1"
       ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
       OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
       Display="Static"
       ErrorMessage="Not an even number!"          
       runat="server"/>




<script language="javascript"> 
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
        if (arguments.Value % 2 == 0 ){
            arguments.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I think a custom validator is overkill for this simple scenario. I feel like some minor mistake is preventing the required validator from validating client-side.

Answer (score 1):

I guess u might be wanting to fire the validation on some events like Button etc.
Then check, have you made the CausesValidation Property of the Button to be true.
for example

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="True" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Comment: Tried it. Didn't make a difference.